# common ways / methods to try to break a SP network

Tags: encryption, substitution-cipher, permutation

I have a very little cryptography background (but a relatively solid maths background) so my below question is very general.

Basically I have been given a SP network with an output to reverse. I thought i could "easily" found the plaintext by reverse-enginnering all the process, using reverse of permutations / substitutions functions until i quickly realized that the S-Box were not bijective at all (several inputs are mapped to the same outputs).

What's more, and this is what is causing me the most trouble, the encryption algorithm has a final round where it does some mixing making the reversal quite complicated.

I am given the lookup table of the S-box and P-Box as well as the encryption algorithm.

I won't post the encryption since this is not the point, but i was wondering what are the typical approaches i can try to solve this, what readings do you advise, etc..

thanks a lot for your help.

Romain

Comment: Are there any unknown key bits stirred into the SP network?  Or, can you compute forwards correctly (and just want to know how to compute backwards)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying :) No, all bits are known. There are many rounds and each round first starts with the bits entering in the s-boxes (8 by 8, i know the lookup table of the s-box), then they got mixed with a key that i also know. In the final round, the 8 bits block got mixed each other. Yes i can compute the forward correctly, I need to go backwards to find at least one solution but have no clue how i can proceed.

Comment: You should try linear and/or differential cryptanalysis, maybe the S-boxes are bad. By the way, you mention the S-boxes are not bijective. That doesn't sound like an SPN.

Comment: Hello, thanks, and yes you are right, i thought it was a SP network but it is most likely not. After some investigation i saw that once the bits go through the s-box, they are mixed each other with some key bits that form an involutory matrix :. That is, if i write the key bits as a matrix if i remultiply the bits again with the same matrix, i get back to the bits i had after the s-box (A² = In), I don't know what i could do with that (again because my s-box are not bijective s i can't reverse them) but surely this is something important.